# How to use NSKeyValueCoding protocol while designing data models?

Tags: ios, model, key-value-coding

I have been trying to create a data model class while following the NSKeyValueCoding protocol. I keep getting the following error:
"Cannot find protocol declaration"
And when I try to #import "NSKeyValueCoding.h" I get the file not found error.

Where can I find this protocol OR how else can it be implemented?

Answer (score 6):

`NSKeyValueCoding` is part of Foundation. So if you `#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>` you already included the header.

`NSKeyValueCoding` is an *informal* protocol. That means that classes do not explicitly conform to it. On the contrary: The protocol claims that the class it is declared upon, `NSObject` in this case, does understand all it's methods.

So: You cannot write a (`NSObject` derived) class in Cocoa that does not conform to KVC.

*But:* You can add non KVC-compliant properties to this class, for example by using funny names for accessors. It might make sense for an implementation to follow the rules for being [KVC compliant](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/Compliant.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002172-BAJEAIEE) or even [KVO compliant](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/KeyValueObserving/Articles/KVOCompliance.html).

Comment: @Nikolai, can you answer my related [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27835715/making-a-protocols-property-kvc-compliant)?